Не выдает обратным запросом значение ячейки А2
```
let token = "7053792653:AAFTukjC7wvExX2Fbm1cHO6lZp7azjiOlMw";

const INLINE1 = {"inline_keyboard": [
  [{"text": "Значение ячейки А2", "callback_data": "Кнопка1" }]
   ],"resize_keyboard":true};


function getMe() {
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/getMe");
  console.log(response.getContentText());
}

function setWebhook() {
  let webAppUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby6hEprhPYwGhwm-H6yV_GDeZe7A4uXa7i7FD9cFZIvCt-c5KrcsBcrVZMznGnQhyBI/exec";
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/setWebhook?url=" + webAppUrl);
  console.log(response.getContentText());
}

function sendText(chat_id, text, keyBoard) {
  let data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "sendMessage",
      chat_id: String(chat_id),
      text: text,
      parse_mode: "HTML",
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify(keyBoard)
    }
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/', data);
}


function answerCallbackQuery(callbackQueryId, text, showAlert) {
  var url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/answerCallbackQuery";
  var payload = {
     callback_query_id : callbackQueryId,
     text: text,
     show_alert: showAlert
  };
  var options = {
     method : "post",
     payload : payload
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}

function doPost(e) {
  let contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ButtonConnect").getRange(1, 1).setValue(JSON.stringify(contents, null, 5));
  let callbackQuery = contents.callback_query;
  if (callbackQuery){
    let chat_id = 801137770;
    let callbackQueryId = callbackQuery.id;
    let value = getValue();
    sendText(chat_id, "Значение ячейки A2: " + value, INLINE1);

    answerCallbackQuery(callbackQueryId,"Результат выполнен", true);
  }

}

function getValue(){
  let val = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ButtonBot").getRange("A2").getValue();
  return val;
}

function send() {
  let chat_id = "801137770";
  let text = "Привет!";
  sendText(chat_id, text, INLINE1);
  }
```


Добро пожаловать на сайт, Фемистокл, ознакомьтесь пожалуйста со справкой как задать вопрос на ru.SO https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Судя по коду всё отрабатывает. Попробуйте через логирование посмотреть действия. Сделать это можно с помощью команды Logger.log()

Скорее всего у вас при выполнении скрипта нет SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() так как таблица не открывается скриптом.
Лучше обратиться к листу SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('SHEET_NAME');
